# Can not connect to windows domain from ubuntu machine in my company

Tags: ubuntu, domain

```
C:\Users\eusername>cmd /k ipconfig /all
Windows IP Configuration
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ehostname
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : ednssuffx.com
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid                     
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : esuffix.com
ednssuffx2.com
    ednssuffx3.com 
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3: 
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Fortinet SSL VPN Virtual Ethernet Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 04-09-04-AA-05-01                
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4: 
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : xxxxx.com 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM #2
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 8C-EC-6B-82-98-2C                 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12: 
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 06-24-D5-20-19-E5                
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes 
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Fortinet Virtual Ethernet Adapter (NDIS 6.30)
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-09-0F-FE-00-01                  
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : example.com
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 #2
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 05-54-D6-D5-59-E4                
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . :
fe80::5443:9233:b591:7855%15(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 40.72.26.126(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 27 Mart 2018 Salı 15:46:16
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 4 Nisan 2018 Çarşamba 15:50:03
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.70.24.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.70.17.200
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234890241254
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . :
00-01-04-01-21-A5-57-0C-64-4C-C8-6D-1E-58
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 12.10.17.202
10.132.74.10
10.70.0.150
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled 
Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection 2: 
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected 
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #2
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-24-46-40-4-E8                  
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

those are from cmd of windows. This machine has windows and ubuntu but ubuntu can not connect to internet. Because domain is registered to windows.

also from settings

ip assignment: automatic dhcp

```
ssid: xxx
protcol: 802.11n
security type : wpa2-enterpies
tyfe of singin info: microfost protected eap peap
ipv4 address: xx.xxx.xx
ipv4 dns servers: xx.x.x.x.x
x.x.x.x
x.x.xx.
primary dns suffix: xx.com
```

like that.

it is ubuntu 1604 and windows is windows 10.

What can i do?

This is company network. All computers are windows so it is not problem for windows. BUt with ubuntu, i cant connect to company wifi because it wants username password and other things. With windows, we dont need any info, it automatically connects. Maybe because of the information setted as you can see in

```
ipconfig all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your IT support whether BYOD devices are supposed to connect to the same network or not, and do they have another network for them.

I'm an administrator for some strict policy networks, having three different access layers with different setting:

1. Internal network needs machine accounts for RADIUS authentication: no user accounts will do.
2. BYOD network allows wide Internet access using RADIUS authentication for AD users, but no connections to company servers.
3. Guest network is easier to join using one time account, but has only limited Internet connectivity.

Your question is not technically solvable, but entirely based on the company policy and AP side settings. Therefore, only your IT department can answer it.